# Insert multiple rows of data into the database wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I know how to insert data into a database one by one but I want to insert multiple pieces of data into database and I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code for a "one-time" insert of data:

```
Bloggers BlogerToaddData = new Blogger
{
     Interest = txtIntrest.Text.ToString(),
     Name = txtname.Text.ToString(),
     Totalposts = Convert.ToInt32(txtPost.Text)
};

bloggerDB.bloggers.InsertOnSubmit(BlogerToaddData);
bloggerDB.SubmitChanges();
```

but how to insert multiple rows of data?

```
Bloggers BlogerToaddData = new Bloggers
{Interest = "wy",Name = "opwm",Totalposts =1},
{Interest = "wy",Name = "opwm",Totalposts =1},
{Interest = "wy",Name = "opwm",Totalposts =1},
```

This is not working

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to create multiple objects. You can either add them one at a time to the list of pending changes:

```
var bloggs = bloggerDB.bloggers;
bloggers.InsertOnSubmit(new Bloggers { Interest = "wy", Name = "opwn", TotalPosts = 1 });
bloggers.InsertOnSubmit(new Bloggers { Interest = "ab", Name = "abcd", TotalPosts = 2 });
bloggers.InsertOnSubmit(new Bloggers { Interest = "cd", Name = "1234", TotalPosts = 3 });
bloggerDB.SubmitChanges();
```

Or use `InsertAllOnSubmit`:

```
bloggerDB.bloggers.InsertAllOnSubmit(new[] {
    new Bloggers { Interest = "wy", Name = "opwn", TotalPosts = 1 },
    new Bloggers { Interest = "ab", Name = "abcd", TotalPosts = 2 },
    new Bloggers { Interest = "cd", Name = "1234", TotalPosts = 3 }
});
bloggerDB.SubmitChanges();
```